Pyomo Dual Variable Fixation
I am using the Pyomo to solve NLP (with ipopt), I am interested to see if there is a way I can fix the values of my dual variable. I am able to extract the information of dual variables using the following link (How to get dual variables in Pyomo?).
Interested to see;
1- How to fix the dual variables? (so that it remains constant throughout the program).
2- Code with the small example will be helpful.
Maybe consider this example;
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

# Create a ConcreteModel object
model = ConcreteModel()
model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.EXPORT)
model.x1 = Var(bounds=(1,5),initialize=1.0)
model.x2 = Var(bounds=(1,5),initialize=5.0)
model.x3 = Var(bounds=(1,5),initialize=3.8)
model.x4 = Var(bounds=(1,5),initialize=1.37)
model.obj = Objective(
    expr=model.x1*model.x4*(model.x1 + model.x2 + model.x3) + model.x3)
model.inequality = Constraint(
    expr=model.x1*model.x2*model.x3*model.x4 >= 25.0)
model.equality = Constraint(
    expr=model.x1**2 + model.x2**2 + model.x3**2 + model.x4**2 == 40.0)
solver.solve(model, tee=True)
results = model.x1(), model.x2(), model.x3(), model.x4(), model.obj()

